# What are the ways of intercepting setting of property on an object?

Tags: javascript, css, prototype, setter, jsdom

I'm trying to figure out how the setting of a property is being intercepted in **jsdom's CSSStyleDeclaration** implementation. This is being done for validation purposes. I want to know where this validation is happening.
[github link](https://github.com/jsdom/cssstyle/blob/b527ed722364dc6d156487c652df100572075dee/lib/CSSStyleDeclaration.js#L69)

This is the line where the setting is happening.
`this[lowercaseName] = value;`

I'm only aware of one method that can be used to intercept this action. Which is usage of [Proxy Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).
But the object in question is not a proxy object.

**Hence Question:** What are the other ways of intercepting(*man in the middle)* the action of setting properties on an object?

**To confirm interception is happening:**

```
const {CSSStyleDeclaration} = require('cssstyle')
const decl = new CSSStyleDeclaration()

decl.setProperty('background-color', 'invalid-value')

decl.getPropertyValue('background-color') // '' returns empty string

decl.setProperty('background-color', '#333')

decl.getPropertyValue('background-color') // '#333'
```

[Use can use this IDE](https://npm.runkit.com/cssstyle)

Comment: What makes you think the setting of the property, `this[lowercaseName] = value`, is being intercepted?

Comment: Because it's being validated. If you try to set an invalid value. It won't do it.

Comment: How are you setting the value? Please provide a code example.

Comment: I've Edited the question to include code example.

Comment: What makes you think that rejection of invalid values is being done via interception rather than being a feature of the browser-native `CSSStyleDeclaration`?

Comment: This is not browser's CSSStyleDeclaration. It's JSDOM's. Perhaps I didn't make that clear in the question. I'll do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the other ways of intercepting(man in the middle) the action of setting properties on an object?

[Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)!

> The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called when there is an attempt to set that property.

In your particular example the colour validation is done by a `parseColor` function called by the `background-color` [setter](https://github.com/jsdom/cssstyle/blob/b527ed722364dc6d156487c652df100572075dee/lib/properties/backgroundColor.js#L25).

Comment: Thank you so much. This checks out. I totally didn't expect setters for each css property.